# Replacing '\t' with sed

Tags: sed, escaping, special-characters

Though many posts address the replacement of tabs in sed, none worked for me in replacing '\t' like in this C statement:

```
char c = '\t'; // to become char c = MMM;
```

I've tried the following recipes and none worked:

```
"s/'\t'/MMM/g"
"s/'\\t'/MMM/g"
"s/' '/MMM/g" // I pressed the <TAB> key
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you invoking sed? sed needs to see the string `'\\t'` depending on the way you are calling it, you might need `'\\\\t'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling sed from the shell, you might fall victim of the shells string handling. That is, the string that should be passed to `sed` should be `"s/'\\t'/MMM"` (where the double quotes `"` are not part of the string).

Most shells remove one level of backslashes from the passed arguments (`"\\"` is passed as `"\"`). Therefore you need to double them.

For single quoted string this is not the case (`'\\t'` is passed as `'\\t'`). Since your pattern contains single quotes you would have to rewrite it to to `'s/'\''\\t'\''/MMM/'` in this case.

```
$ sed "s/'\\\\t'/MMM/" <<<"char c = '\t';"
char c = MMM;
```

but you wouldn't REALLY write 4 escapes, you'd just use a bracket expression:

```
$ sed "s/'[\]t'/MMM/" <<<"char c = '\t';"
char c = MMM;
```

or to avoid exposing the rest of the script to the shell:

```
$ sed 's/'\''\\t'\''/MMM/' <<<"char c = '\t';"
char c = MMM;
```

Here's the difference - lets say instead of `MMM` you want to replace `\t` with `costs $25`:

```
$ sed 's/'\''\\t'\''/costs $25/' <<<"char c = '\t';"
char c = costs $25;

$ sed "s/'[\]t'/costs $25/" <<<"char c = '\t';"
char c = costs 5;
```

The double-quoted script fails because you're exposing it to the shell for interpretation and, depending on your shell, it reads `$25` as `$2` (the value of the 2nd positional parameter passed to the shell) then `5`.

Comment: Alternatively: `sed '/char c/s/\\t/MMM/' <<< "char c = '\t';"`